# Findbugs and Maven 3.x

Tags: maven, findbugs

Has anyone managed to get findbugs 2.3.1, 2.3.2-SNAPSHOT or 2.4-SNAPSHOT to work with a Maven 3.x project?

I always end up with:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.codehaus.mojo:findbugs-maven-plugin:2.4-SNAPSHOT:findbugs
>   (default-cli) on project cular-db: An
>   error has occurred in FindBugs Report
>   report generation. Could not find
>   matching constructor for:
>   org.codehaus.mojo.findbugs.FindbugsReportGenerator(org.codehaus.doxia.module.xhtml.XhtmlSink,
>   java.util.PropertyResourceBundle,
>   java.io.File,
>   org.apache.maven.doxia.tools.DefaultSiteTool)

I tried all the latest possible versions. It does not matter if I use findbugs:fingbugs or only the site goal. It is specified with

```
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>${findbugs.version}</version>
      <configuration>
        <threshold>High</threshold>
        <effort>Default</effort>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: Run with -X flag, there is not so much to tell, it just says no matching constructor.

Comment: It says you should use 2.3.2-SNAPSHOT with maven 3 http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MFINDBUGS-126

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On 2011/03/20, Findbugs 2.3.2 was been released, with Maven 3 support.

[Announcement](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/ANN-Maven-Findbugs-plugin-version-2-3-2-Released-td4214722.html)

[Release Notes](http://jira.codehaus.org/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?version=16272&projectId=11701)

This means that you should be able to use the latest non-snapshot version of the plugin (version 2.3.2 or later) with Maven 3.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.2</version>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comment you should use findbugs version `2.3.2-SNAPSHOT` with `Maven 3`. I started a project with using `maven-quickstart-archetype` and executed `mvn findbugs:findbugs` and the reports are generated successfully without any problems.

```
[INFO] ****** FindBugsMojo execute *******
[INFO] Inside canGenerateReport..... false
[INFO] Inside canGenerateReport..... skip false, classFilesDirectory.exists() true
[INFO] canGenerate is true
[INFO] ****** FindBugsMojo executeReport *******
[INFO] Temp File is /home/umut/noinstall/dummy/target/findbugsTemp.xml
[INFO] Fork Value is true
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2:56.550s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Jan 10 11:05:13 PST 2011
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/55M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The following is the my `pom.xml`.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.dummy</groupId>
    <artifactId>dummy</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>dummy</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>codehaus.snapshots</id>
            <url>http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <configuration>
                    <threshold>High</threshold>
                    <effort>Default</effort>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

BTW you are right it is not working with `2.3.1` but I did not try `2.4-SNAPSHOT`.

Answer (score 1):

Just a short note for anyone with the same problem: My experience is that it does work with `2.3.2-SNAPSHOT` but **not** with `2.4-SNAPSHOT`. (`2.4-SNAPSHOT` causes the same error.)