# What does Apple's update to Java 1.6.0_24 break?

Tags: java, maven, osx-snow-leopard

Apple's update [Java for Max OS X 10.6 Update 4](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4562) breaks [maven-sling-plugin 2.0.2](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.sling/maven-sling-plugin), version 2.0.4 fixes the problem. What else has broken for people with Java 1.6.0_24 on Mac OS X 10.6.6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this Java Update Apple delivers maven3 and i think the version 2.0.2 of maven-sling-plugin has problems with maven3.

Comment: Nice, I saw the maven3 install but didn't realize that it was new.

Answer (score 0):

There's a whole thread on how Google AppServer is broken by this update as well.
http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4712

This thread also provides a fix/workaround.

Comment: I don't run Google AppServer so this is news to me.

Answer (score 0):

findbugs 2.3.1 appears to be broken by this update, at least the way I had it configured and working in the previous version of maven.  findbugs 2.3 is supposed to work with maven 3 so this could be my fault, but it still stinks to have maven updated behind my back.

http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MFINDBUGS-122
also
[Findbugs and Maven 3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649749/findbugs-and-maven-3-x)

Comment: That explains why some of my pom file have been complaining.

Comment: I resolved this by using 2.3.2-SNAPSHOT, but it's obviously sub-optimal to use a SNAPSHOT version.